# Visual Studio Templates - create files at solution level

Tags: visual-studio, templates, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I have a definition for a visual studio solution.  I achieve this by defining a top level template for the solution and then two project templates.

Here's the solution template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Hosted Process (.net Core)</Name>
        <Description>.NET Core hosted process with boilerplate code for building container/linux deployable applications.</Description>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <DefaultName>HostedProcessApp</DefaultName>
        <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
      <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink TargetFolderName="$projectname$" ProjectName="$projectname$">
           HostedProcessTemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink TargetFolderName="Tests" ProjectName="$projectname$.Tests" CopyParameters="true">
           HostedProcessTemplateTests\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

This works well!  But what I now would like is to create items at solution level and not down in the projects themselves (I have a nuget file and .gitignore I want to exist for every solution created using the template).

I've tried adding the items to the solution template as "ProjectItem" but doesn't work:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Hosted Process (.net Core)</Name>
        <Description>.NET Core hosted process with boilerplate code for building container/linux deployable applications.</Description>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <DefaultName>HostedProcessApp</DefaultName>
        <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
      <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="nuget.config">nuget.config</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="Coverlet.runsettings">Coverlet.runsettings</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$projectname$.sln.DotSettings">$projectname$.sln.DotSettings</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName=".dockerignore">.dockerignore</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectTemplateLink TargetFolderName="$projectname$" ProjectName="$projectname$">
           HostedProcessTemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink TargetFolderName="Tests" ProjectName="$projectname$.Tests" CopyParameters="true">
           HostedProcessTemplateTests\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Has anyone managed to get this going?  Thanks for pointers in advance!